# what are some common uses of closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

A closure is basically an inner/nested function.  What are some of the most common examples of nested functions in popular js frameworks?  In what scenarios would you choose to write a custom closure?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` is probably the most widely-used closure ever.

Comment: Umm read your school book.

Comment: Look up "scope" and "variables" while trying to understand "closures"

Comment: This isn't a bad question. The problem is "the question doesn't show any research effort". Also saying "read your school book" is not helpful.